# Google App Engine devserver redeployment

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I have been using GAE and Endpoints for a couple weeks now. I see when I make changes to my code, the devserver will automatically pick up the changes and I am able to sometimes run tests against my updated API in the local API browser. However, I have also noticed some instances where it appears the changes were not picked up automatically and my API browser was hitting old code.

What is the proper process for updating my application to test locally? Do I have to restart my devserver? Do I need to refresh my browser and build new request objects? Can I simply execute a previous request again? (from experience, the last question appears to be no).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While working with the Development Server, I have found that it is best to :

- Restart the Server &
- Refresh the browser to ensure that any updated services definition is picked up by the API Explorer.

Comment: Thanks Romin. I was hoping this would not be the case since auto deployment updates seem to work sometimes. And thanks for your Google Cloud Endpoints tutorial. I went through it a week ago. Very thorough!